# Turn method ES6 find() to something in ES5

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, indexof, es5-compatiblity

I need to join values of 2 arrays of objects and make a third one out of it. I use es6 method find() to make it but i've been asked some es5 code for this piece of logic. I wanted to use indexOf() but i dont know how to make it unfortunately...

thanks for your very kind help.

```
const caByEmployee = [{
        id: 8,
        period1: 652.40,
        period2: 3831.73,
        name: 'Tam'
    },
    {
        id: 18,
        period1: 421.95,
        period2: 1036.18,
        name: 'Nathalie'
    },
    {
        id: 20,
        period1: 300.5,
        period2: 1179.15,
        name: 'Liliane'
    }
]

const attendanceByEmployee = [{
         id : 1,
         period1 : 0,
         period2 : 86
    },
    {
         id : 8,
         period1 : 98,
         period2 : 520
    },
    {
         id : 18,
         period1 : 70,
         period2 : 49
    },
    {
         id : 20,
         period1 : 4,
         period2 : 227
    }
]

const averageCartByEmployee = caByEmployee.map(function (ca) {
    var attendance = attendanceByEmployee.find(function (attendance) {
        return attendance.id === ca.id;
    });

    return {
        id     : ca.id,
        name   : ca.name,
        period1: ca.period1 / attendance.period1 || 0,
        period2: ca.period2 / attendance.period2 || 0
    };
});
```

this give a result like so which is totally fine but not made with es5

```
[ { id: 8, 
    name: 'Tam', 
    period1: 6.657142857142857, 
    period2: 7.368711538461539 }, 
  { id: 18, 
    name: 'Nathalie', 
    period1: 6.027857142857143, 
    period2: 21.1465306122449 }, 
  { id: 20, 
    name: 'Liliane', 
    period1: 75.125, 
    period2: 5.194493392070485 } ]
```

Comment: `<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Array.prototype.find"></script>`

Answer (score 1):

Polyfilling [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) is trivial, see the link for one such polyfill but there are others out there.

You can't use `indexOf` because it looks for the thing actually in the array, and you want to match by `id`. (You could use `findIndex`, but it's also not an ES5 method.)

If you don't want to polyfill, you'll want a simple `for` loop, `break`ing when you find an entry with the matching `id`.